# Using an array of strings that have the same meaning as a "lookup_value" in the MATCH() excel function

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, match, vba

I have a large table of market values with rows labeled with each `asset` name and each column representing each `month` between `2000` and `2014`.

The table I have is currently blank and I want to use an `index` / `match` function to search for the data corresponding to each `date` / `asset` combo in data that was submitted to me. My problem is that this submitted data is slightly inconsistent in how it names assets at different points at time. One year may have an `asset` called `Goldman Sachs Strategic` and another year may label the same `asset` as `GS Strategic Income`.

I would like to allow for the user of the spreadsheet to type names that are actually equivalent to each other. On a sheet called `equivalent names` I would like have cell `A1` be `Goldman Sachs Strategic` and `B1` to be `GS Strategic Income`. I was hoping there was a way to make `A1:B1` an array that could then be used as a `lookup` value within my `index` / `match` function.

I realize this probably is not the way to approach this problem but I have a very limited dictionary of solutions because I have limited experience coding and using excel. I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of a solution that would actually work because I am assuming inconsistent data is a problem many people have dealt with before. Thanks a lot for any help that you can offer!

Comment: Without knowing the full extent of your programming knowledge, does this help at all? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59482

Comment: Any idea on how many duplicates we're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created some random data to test with

[image: Sample Random Data]

I then created the following table on the second worksheet.

[image: Summary Table]

The last 5 columns (`2010,2011,2012,2013,2014`) represent the year to year names. Using these names (which may or may not be blank), we simply use a series of concatenated `SUMIF()` functions.

Because you didn't provide specific data, I understand that this answer might not fully fit your question, so if there is anything that is incorrect, let me know. Otherwise, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is an elegant approach. And thanks for the index/match against multiple criteria article.